# Collections.sort() isn't sorting in the right order

Tags: java, sorting, collections

I have this code in Java:

```
List<String> unSorted = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> beforeHash = new ArrayList<String>();
String[] unSortedAux, beforeHashAux; 
String line = null;

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\CPD\\temp0.txt"));
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
        unSorted.add(line);  
        beforeHash.add(line.split("#")[0]); 

    }
    reader.close();

    Collections.sort(beforeHash);
    beforeHashAux = beforeHash.toArray(new String[beforeHash.size()]);
    unSortedAux = unSorted.toArray(new String[unSorted.size()]);

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(beforeHashAux));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(unSortedAux));
```

It reads a file named temp0.txt, which contains:

```
Carlos Magno#261
Mateus Carl#12
Analise Soares#151
Giancarlo Tobias#150
```

My goal is to sort the names in the string, without the string after "#". I am using beforeHash.add(line.split("#")[0]); to do this. The problem is that it reads correctly the file, but it sorts in the wrong order. The correspondent outputs are:

```
[Analise Soares, Giancarlo Tobias, Mateus Carl, Carlos Magno]
[Carlos Magno#261, Mateus Carl#12, Analise Soares#151, Giancarlo Tobias#150]
```

The first result is the "sorted" one, note that "Carlos Magno" comes after "Mateus Carl". I cannot find the problem in my code.

Comment: No need for the I/O code in your example. You could simplify it to a constant list to save us all from making files.

Comment: What is `beforeHash`? Can you show us its declaration?

Comment: You've left out all the important information: What is the declaration of `beforeHash`, and the type of the contained elements.

Comment: sorry about that, I will edit it

Comment: beforeHash is anArrayList<String>();, I know it is the wrong name, it basically takes the part of the string that comes before the "#"(hash) and put it on a list

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that "Carlos Magno" starts with a [Unicode byte-order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).

If you copy and paste your sample text (`[Analise ... Carlos Magno]`) into the [Unicode Explorer](https://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Unicode#explorer) you'll see that just before the "C" of Carlos Magno, you've got U+FEFF.

Basically, you'll need to strip that when reading the file. The easiest way to do this is just use:

```
line = line.replace("\ufeff", "");
```

... or check first:

```
if (line.startsWith("\ufeff")) {
    line = line.substring(1);
}
```

Note that you should really specify the encoding you want to use when opening the file - use a `FileInputStream` wrapped in an `InputStreamReader`.

Comment: +1 But I'm reluctant to click tinyurl links... why not post the full link to http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Unicode.aspx#explorer?

Comment: @Duncan: Because it's easier to remember http://tinyurl.com/unicode-explorer, and others may want to remember it for themselves. You can always use http://preview.tinyurl.com/unicode-explorer if you want to - but it's not clear why you'd trust csharpindepth.com over a tinyurl.com link...

Comment: Oh, thanks for the answer, I was going nuts with this problem.

Comment: Just curious, how might someone who had never been burned by invisible characters go around discovering this? Is this just something that you read about/experience once and then remember?

Comment: @user3580294: Sort of. First I reproduced the problem using the text in the post, then I started looking at what the data actually consisted of.

Comment: Ah, I see. That's something I'll have to keep in mind for future use. Thanks!